# How do I Implement router in CanJS

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-routing

I am taking help of the https://github.com/thinkadoo/Projects application. I have built a similar app with the help of this one. My application is using d3 charts instead of the one this uses. My app initializes the routers as

```
  var patientStatus = new PatientStatus('#application', {'credentials':Credentials,'secret':Secret});
```

Now if i want to implement Router then what changes should be done?
Here is my JSFiddle with both implementations. The first one is working. But the later part where in I am initializing the Router doesnt seem to work.
http://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/YMAjm/

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5YH5/) that shows how routing works:

```
  var Router = can.Control({
    defaults: {}
  }, {
    init: function() {
      // this.element.html(can.view('#index', {}));
    },

    ':type/:id route': function(data) {
        console.log('Type:', data.type);
        console.log('Id:', data.id);
    }
  });

  can.route.ready(false);
  new Router('#content');
  can.route.ready(true);
```

Basically, what you do is initialize your named placeholders and tell the controller that this should be handled by the `route` processor. Now if you go to a URL like `#!test/23` the data of the handler will contain a `type` and `id` property.

Comment: Hey Daff thanks a lot. It is working.  I implemented your as per your suggestion but now my problem is only the first controller is invoked and the rest routes direct yto the same one. I have many routes like Projects, Status, Detail etc... After running the code mentioned in the fiddle every link shows the projects view. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sweety1112/YMAjm/1/ . Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: My URL is as follows 1.MyProjectHub/index.html#!projects, 2./MyProjectHub/index.html#!status, 3./MyProjectHub/index.html#!detail

Comment: You don't need the `:`. That indicates a variable. If you want to match the actual rout, just write it like `projects route` which will exactly match `#!projects`.