# Location.hash returns empty string

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canjs, canjs-routing

I am currently using jQuery, Twitter Bootstrap and CanJS for my web application. I'm trying to implement routing with CanJS. I'm using Bootstrap's tab, and when I click on a tab, it was supposed to bring #tabSearch, #tabUser or #tabPermissions, but the hash is returned with an empty string. 
What am I doing wrong?

I´m using this to change the tabs:

```
     TabControl = can.Control.extend({}, {
        init: function (element, options) {
        element.find('a[href="' + options.defaultTab + '"]').tab('show');
        this.userSearch = null;
        this.userForm = null;
    }
    , 'a[data-toggle="tab"] show': function (e) {
        this.options.tabChangeCallback(e);
    }
});

     UserTab = new TabControl('#tabctrlUser', {
       defaultTab: '#tabSearch',
       tabChangeCallback: function (e) {

        if (e.context.hash == '#tabSearch') {                
            if (!this.userSearch) {
                this.userSearch = new FormUserQuery('#tabSearch', {});
            } 
        } else if (e.context.hash == '#tabUser') { 
            if (!this.userForm) {
                this.userForm = new FormUser('#tabUser', {});
            }
            this.userForm.renderView(currentUser);
        } else if (e.context.hash == '#tabPermissions') {                
            new FormPermissions('#tabPermissions', {});

        }
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
<ul id="tabctrlUser" class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li><a href="#tabSearch"  data-toggle="tab">Pesquisar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabUser"  data-toggle="tab">Cadastrar/Alterar</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabPermissions"  data-toggle="tab">Acessos</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tabSearch"></div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tabUser"></div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tabPermissions"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [can.route](http://canjs.com/docs/can.route.html) or [can.Control.Route](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control.route.html), the way you do it is complicated take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757890/how-do-i-implement-router-in-canjs)
Also there's 2 [good](http://bitovi.com/blog/2012/05/hashchange-routing-can-route-2.html) [articles](http://bitovi.com/blog/2012/05/hashchange-routing-can-route-2.html) about routing

look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/cherifGsoul/6538931#file-tbcanjs)

http://jsfiddle.net/Z9Cv5/2/light/

```
var HistoryTabs = can.Control({
  init: function( el ) {

    // hide all tabs
    var tab = this.tab;
    this.element.children( 'li' ).each(function() {
      tab( $( this ) ).hide();
    });

    // activate the first tab
    var active = can.route.attr(this.options.attr);
    this.activate(active);
  },
  "{can.route} {attr}" : function(route, ev, newVal, oldVal){
    this.activate(newVal, oldVal)
  },
  // helper function finds the tab for a given li
  tab: function( li ) {
    return $( li.find( 'a' ).attr( 'href' ) );
  },
  // helper function finds li for a given id
  button : function(id){
    // if nothing is active, activate the first
    return id ? this.element.find("a[href=#"+id+"]").parent()  : 
                this.element.children( 'li:first' );
  },
  // activates 
  activate: function( active, oldActive ){
    // deactivate the old active
    var oldButton = this.button(oldActive).removeClass('active');
    this.tab(oldButton).hide();
    // activate new
    var newButton = this.button(active).addClass('active');
    this.tab(newButton).show();
  },
  "li click" : function(el, ev){
    // prevent the default setting
    ev.preventDefault();
    // update the route data
    can.route.attr(this.options.attr, this.tab(el)[0].id)
  }
});

// configure routes
can.route(":component",{
  component: "model",
  person: "mihael"
});

can.route(":component/:person",{
  component: "model",
  person: "mihael"
});

// adds the controller to the element
new HistoryTabs( '#components',{attr: 'component'});
new HistoryTabs( '#people',{attr: 'person'});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with CanJS, but this could have something to do that anchor **click** event happens *before* navigation, and **location.hash** is set *after*. E.g. if (as a test) you define your link as

```
<a href="#tabSearch" onclick="tabChangeCallback()">Pesquisar</a>
```

And in plain vanilla JS try

```
function tabChangeCallback() {
  alert(location.hash)
}
```

It will display blank.

But if you try something like

```
function tabChangeCallback() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       alert(location.hash)
   }, 100)
}
```

It *will* display the hash. So in your case either set your code to be executed on timeout after main event or (and I think it's a better option) instead of hash you should read `href` attribute of the anchor element that caused the event.

*Update* The plain JS example below shows how to get the hash value without timeout:

```
function tabChangeCallback(e) {

     var elem = e ? e.target : event.srcElement

     alert(elem.getAttribute("href"))
}
```

Comment: In your event handler code you should have access to element that caused the event. Usually it's something like `e.target` or `e.srcElement'. When you click `<a href="#tabSearch"...` anchor - that would be this element, and by reading its `href` attribute you should get "#tabSearch"

Comment: P.S. Updated my answer to illustrate the approach